# Is it possible to have read not block, but write block for pipes?

Tags: c, unix, select, posix, pipe

`man 2 select` states the following under BUGS:

> Under Linux, select() may report a socket file descriptor as "ready for
>          reading",  while nevertheless a subsequent read blocks.  This could for
>          example happen when data has arrived but  upon  examination  has  wrong
>          checksum and is discarded.  There may be other circumstances in which a
>          file descriptor is spuriously reported as ready.  Thus it may be  safer
>          to use O_NONBLOCK on sockets that should not block.

Thus, my `read` calls need to not block and therefore I have marked my pipe file descriptors `O_NONBLOCK`. However, I want `write` calls to block until data is written to the pipe.

Is it possible to have `write` block when writing data to the pipe, but have `read` not block the reading end? Is it legal for instance to call `fcntl` on one end only after the pipe has been created, since read and write ends have separate file descriptors?

Answer (score 2):

You surely can remove O_NONBLOCK flag before each `write` with `fcntl` and put it back after `write` completes. However, it seems better to keep the socket non-blocking all the time and to put `write` into a loop until it finishes. In order not to overload the CPU, put a select which will block the process until the socket is ready for write.

So, the writing code will look like:

```
int blockingWriteOnNonBlockingFd(int fd, char *buf, int size) {
  fd_set wset, w;
  int    n, r;
  FD_ZERO(&wset);
  FD_SET(fd, &wset);
  n = 0;
  while (n < size) {
    w = wset;
    select(fd+1, NULL, &w, NULL, NULL);
    r = write(fd, buf+n, size-n);
    if (r <= 0) {
       if (r<0 && (errno == EWOULDBLOCK || errno == EAGAIN)) r = 0;
       else { /* broken connection */ break; }
    }
    n += r;
  }
  return(n);
}
```

Comment: Could I set the write FD to blocking and the read FD to non-blocking, since they are separate file descriptors when using pipes?

Comment: Yes, you can. I've probably wrong understood the original question. I though you wanted to read/write from/to the same socket.